Component with Antd-Table inside and pass generic types
I have a reusable react-component in which i'm using an antd-table.
import type { TableProps } from 'antd/lib/table';

export function TableComponent_TRY<RecordType>(props: TableProps<RecordType>) {
  const {
    columns,
    dataSource,
    rowKey,
    rowClassName,
    rowSelection,
    pagination,
    className,
    loading,
    expandable,
    showSorterTooltip,
  } = props;

/*
~ Deleted unnecessary code
*/

    return (
        <Table
              size='small'
              showSorterTooltip={showSorterTooltip}
              className={className}
              rowClassName={rowClassName}
              loading={loading}
              pagination={pagination}
              dataSource={dataSource}
              columns={columns}
              rowKey={rowKey}
              expandable={expandable}
              rowSelection={rowSelection}
        />
    );
}

Now im getting multiple errors like:


Type 'string | RowClassName<RecordType> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | RowClassName<object> | undefined'.



Type 'ColumnsType<RecordType> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ColumnsType<object> | undefined'.


same goes for "rowKey", "dataSource", "expandable", "rowSelection".  (all generic types)


Maybe even more if i would use other features of antd-table.
I've already tried to create my own interface for that component:
interface IAppProps<RecordType> {
    columns: ColumnsType<object>,
    rowKey: string | GetRowKey<object>,
    ...
}
export function TableComponent_TRY<RecordType>(props: IAppProps<RecordType>) {
    ...
}

but resulted in:
<TableComponent_TRY columns={columns} />

Type 'ColumnsType<tick_Step>' is not assignable to type 'ColumnsType<object>'.

How do i properly out-source the antd-table while still retain types?
PS: Kinda new to generics

Replace object with RecordType

@MuhammadNoumanRafique thats the problem. There is no 'object' in the first place.
'TableProps' comes directly from antd itself, since it is imported, and there is also 'RecordType'.
So 'object' only occurs in the error-message.
